# Vehicle usage optimization using GTFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, knapsack-problem, gtfs

I have a GTFS feed defined for my fleet. This tells the routes, trips and timings. Now using this GTFS feed, is it possible to optimize the utilization of my fleet's vehicles? Can I schedule the vehicles such that once it completes a trip, it can be assigned to serve a trip of another route?

I have constriants such as no vehicle should be running more than 12 hours, every vehicle will undergo a health check for 2 hrs, etc.

To me this sounds like a case of the Knapsack problem.

If such a project exists, kindly let me know. Is there an algorithm that can solve this problem?

Thanks,

Yash

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a question that is typically assigned to a scheduling system, one which would produce GTFS files from the get-go. In smaller systems, this actually is not difficult to do, but as the number of routes (or "trip patterns") increases, the process gets more complex.

Before you undertake any project like this, I suggest reading over [the TCRP manual on scheduling](http://www.nap.edu/catalog/14257/tcrp-report-135-controlling-system-costs-basic-and-advanced-scheduling), paying close attention to the terms "cycle time," "headway," and "interlining."

While I'd love to help more, I don't have time right now to get into the specifics. I performed a similar analysis with automatically collected cycle times on a limited set of routes in my [masters thesis](http://hdl.handle.net/1721.1/60806), starting on page 118.

I hope this helps. If you have any follow-up questions, post a comment and I'll respond when I have time.